# Saving user interaction without overloading the database

Tags: php, database

I'm currently working on an concept of an E-learning system and wondering, how social networks like facebook are saving the user input like (e.g Thumps Up, Comments and so on). Or how does StackOverflow save the questions? In my specific case I need to save interactions like exercise results, user logins and more. Do you have some tips?

Thanks in advance,

Philip

Comment: They send a request to a script on the server, that updates the information in their databases

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yes, that's clear to me, but how do they manage the database without overloading the server?

Comment: They run on more than 1 server, more even than 2 or 3.... unless you're going to have millions of concurrent users on your e-learning system, you probably don't need to worry about that quite yet

Comment: [Relevant](https://gigaom.com/2012/08/13/facebooks-number-of-servers-soar-to-an-estimated-180k/). And that was in 2012..

Comment: Do you think they are creating a new table for every new user or are they identifying it otherwise?

Comment: No, they don't have a new table for every individual user..... that would be completely inefficient; but they do have multiple databases in the same way they have multiple servers

Comment: @DevTec They definitely do not create a new table for every user and even if they did such a practice would not help a database server in any way, not to mention it would be grossly bad database design.

Comment: OK, thanks to everybody for your helpful responses!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create relational table like user ---> comments, thumbs up etc. Problem is when you retrieve data application or db has to lookup over the db.

So you can (comments, thumbs up etc) save as JSON object.

"Post" Table and think about following columns in this table.

id:1
post: XYZ
comments: {["user":123,"comment":"test comment"]} 
thumbs:{"total":3,["user":13,"thumbs":true]}

So you an retrieve efficiently single SELECT query those data. When you save it you must convert to JSON object.

You can try NoSQL database too.

Answer (score 1):

As Damith Said you should maybe look at NoSQL.

If you went down this route maybe take a look at the idea of **Event Sourcing**

> So then, what is event sourcing? Event sourcing is another shift in
>   paradigm, which blew me away at first. When using a regular database,
>   we usually create a record in the database and then perform some
>   updates on that same record, read it a few times until it eventually
>   gets deleted. Essentially we’re always saving the latest snapshot of
>   the data. If you take a step back, you see that actually we’re
>   deleting data all the time. Whenever you perform a delete or an update
>   in your database you are deleting data. Think about that for a moment,
>   do you really want to delete data? How do you know that in few months
>   time this data is not going to be important?

Take a read of = http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/12/05/introduction-to-domain-driven-design-cqrs-and-event-sourcing/

Comment: Unfortunately i can't vote this answer up, but thanks!

Comment: no problem mate, hope it might of helped

Comment: Now I upvoted you. Thanks for the answer.